# Googlecode jQuery datatables inline edit restrict to one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, editing, google-code

I think I want to use [datatables editable googlecode](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html)

You can find an example inline editing here:

http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html

**But, can we restrict the editing to one column only?**

Update me! How?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes! nothing found to me ! @putvande